# No puedo conectar Intel Edison a WiFi en Android Things

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al querer realizar el [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/edison.html)) de Android Things usando mi Intel Edison.

Al querer conectar la Edison, esta no se conecta , lo sé por que al correr el comando:

```
$ adb logcat -d | grep Wifi
```

No me aparece lo que dice el tutorial:

> ```
> V WifiWatcher: Network state changed to CONNECTED
> V WifiWatcher: SSID changed: ...
> I WifiConfigurator: Successfully connected to ...
> ```

Mucho menos al querer hacer el Ping ...

Comment: Listo! Soy un poco nuevo en estas cosas. 
Al querer copiar el código del tutorial me encontré con que no dejaba un espacio al final del código, al ingresar mi password

es decir:

adb shell am startservice \
-n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
enter code here
-a WifiSetupService.Connect \
enter code here
-e ssid NombreWifi \
-e passphrase ContraseñaWifi

despues de "ContraseñaWifi" hay que dejar un espacio, es decir:

Answer (score 0):

Listo! Soy un poco nuevo en estas cosas. 
Al querer copiar el código del tutorial me encontré con que no dejaba un espacio al final del código, al ingresar mi password

**es decir:**

```
adb shell am startservice \

-n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \

-a WifiSetupService.Connect \

-e ssid NombreWifi \

-e passphrase ContraseñaWifi
```

**despues de "ContraseñaWifi" hay que dejar un espacio, es decir:**

```
adb shell am startservice \
-n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
-a WifiSetupService.Connect \
enter code here
-e ssid NombreWifi \
-e passphrase ContraseñaWifi" "
```

(espacio, sin comillas)

Al final del código, después de la contraseña, hay que dejar un espacio.